# Проектирование крупного приложения на vue

Tags: vue.js

Хочется получить ответ от разработчиков, кто делал крупные ентерпрайз приложения на vue.

Сегодня зашла дискуссия о том, что проектировать нужно в духе "микросервисов", где каждый отдельный модуль продукта - отдельное приложение на vue, но соединенный в один интерфейс с помощью проксирования nginx. Грубо говоря, имеем кучу сайтов в одном сайте.

То есть, для каждого модуля свои vuex, router, свои зависимости и прочее. 
Но, по мнению коллег, в случае выхода новых фреймворков, мы безболезненно перепишем один модуль за другим, если понадобится. Так ли это на самом деле, и оправданы ли затраты ресурсов ради этого?

Я выступил противником данного подхода. Он кажется тяжелым, сложным и никто так вроде бы не делает. Я лично такой практики не встречал. SPA фреймворк на то и SPA.

Собственно, за "классический" spa я и выступаю - да, на выходе мы получим огромный бандл из всех модулей, где каждого конкретному пользователя нужна лишь небольшая его часть (например, разные модули для разных отделов, где каждый пользуется своим функционалом, и он никак не пересекается с другим). Это является главным контраргументом моего подхода - то, что, вероятно, определенный код может попасть в нежелательные руки и вообще.

Хотелось бы обсудить этот кейс, и как лучше подойти к проектированию приложения.

Для большей наглядности, как пример, можно разобрать приложение CRM, где одним нужна только страница выгрузки отчетов, а вторым, скажем, аналитика продаж.

Comment: Асинхронные компоненты помогут Вам https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Короткий ответ.

Для вашей задачи изобрели webpack. Вы можете писать одно SPA но сконфигурировать его так, что бы собирать нужные бандлы с отдельными файлами. Разделяю логику клиента и заказчика например.

---

Теперь подробнее. Vue очень модульный фраемворк. Уберите из вашего приложения Vuex и оно не упадет (пусть и будет работать не правильно). Так же и с любым компонентом. Если вы верно посотроите архитектуру приложения, то все то что вам нужно будет в одном SPA.

Никто не запретит Вам создавать удобную для вас иерархию. Например:

- src

  - common

    - components
    - views
    - router.js
    - store.js
  - client

    - components
    - views
    - router.js
    - store.js
  - operator

    - components
    - views
    - router.js
    - store.js

> То есть, для каждого модуля свои vuex, router, свои зависимости и прочее. Но, по мнению коллег, в случае выхода новых фреймворков, мы безболезненно перепишем один модуль за другим, если понадобится. Так ли это на самом деле, и оправданы ли затраты ресурсов ради этого?

**Задачи нужно решать тогда когда они появляются.** Усложнить архитектуру <s>и страдать от этого</s> вы сможете всегда.

> Сегодня зашла дискуссия о том, что проектировать нужно в духе "микросервисов", где каждый отдельный модуль продукта - отдельное приложение на vue, но соединенный в один интерфейс с помощью проксирования nginx.

Микросервисная архитектура подходит если у вас несколько команд которые работают над строго определенными кусками кода. Например одна команда пишет только клиент, а вторая только "оператора". В таком случае использование микросервисной архитектуры вообще имеет смысл.

**В будущем если приложение станет действительно очень большим, Вы все еще соможете относительно безболезненно разделить его.** *(Я не думаю что такая задача отнимет больше одного рабочего дня, одного сотрудника)*

Конечно однозначного ответа на Ваш вопрос нет, но в качестве отступления на хабре есть отличный [перевод](https://habr.com/ru/company/infopulse/blog/330708/) в котором на примерах рассказывают что излишнее усложнение, никогда не ведет ни к чему хорошему.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! А где можно почитать про конфигурацию вебпак для этих целей? Признаться, никогда его не настраивал.